# How do I show only the horizontal gridlines in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on my page, but it looks a bit too busy with all of the gridlines in there. Is there any simple way to only show the horizontal lines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in Css:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td {
    border-right-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
```